# ExoPlayer with ViewPager and multiple ViewHolder types

Tags: android-recyclerview, exoplayer2.x, android-viewpager2

I have a ViewPager2 with 2 types of ViewHolder. One is Image and the other is Video. I want the video to play with the Exoplayer so i try to implement the normal functionality, When the video enters start play, onPage changed stop the previous and start the new (if its a video). Here is what i do

```
private val pageChangeCallback = object: ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
        override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
            val attachmentItem = viewAdapter.getItemFromPosition(position) ?: return
            supportActionBar?.let {
                it.title = attachmentItem.toFullNameSender()
                it.subtitle = attachmentItem.date.formatAs(CHAT_ROOM_DATE_SEPARATOR, withUtc = false)
            }
}

override fun onCreate() {

        viewAdapter = ChatRoomGalleryAdapter(this)
        galleryViewPager.adapter = viewAdapter

        galleryViewModel.attachments.observe(this) {
            it?.let {
                viewAdapter.files = it
            }
        }
 
        galleryViewPager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(pageChangeCallback)

}

override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        galleryViewPager.unregisterOnPageChangeCallback(pageChangeCallback)
    }
```

Adapter class

```
class ChatRoomGalleryAdapter(
    private val appContext: Context
) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    var files = listOf<AttachmentItem>()
        set(value) {
            field = value
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
         return when (files[position].extension.fileTypeByExtension()) {
            IMAGE_TYPE -> IMAGE_ITEM
            VIDEO_TYPE -> VIDEO_ITEM
            else -> -1
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder =
        when (viewType) {
            IMAGE_ITEM -> ChatRoomGalleryImageViewHolder.from(parent)
            VIDEO_ITEM -> ChatRoomGalleryVideoViewHolder.from(parent)
            else -> ChatRoomGalleryImageViewHolder.from(parent)
        }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        when (getItemViewType(position)) {
            IMAGE_ITEM -> {
                (holder as ChatRoomGalleryImageViewHolder).bind(files[position])
            }
            VIDEO_ITEM -> {
                (holder as ChatRoomGalleryVideoViewHolder).bind(files[position])
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = files.size

    fun getItemFromPosition(position: Int): AttachmentItem? =
        files.getOrNull(position)

    class ChatRoomGalleryImageViewHolder internal constructor(itemView: View) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        private val image: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.galleryImage)

        fun bind(attachmentItem: AttachmentItem) {
            Glide
                .with(itemView.context)
                .load(
                    File(
                        attachmentItem.fetchFile()
                    )
                )
                .into(image)
        }

        companion object {
            fun from(parent: ViewGroup): ChatRoomGalleryImageViewHolder =
                ChatRoomGalleryImageViewHolder(
                    LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                        .inflate(R.layout.chat_room_gallery_image_item, parent, false)
                )
        }
    }

    class ChatRoomGalleryVideoViewHolder internal constructor(itemView: View) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        private val video: PlayerView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.galleryVideo)

        private val exoPlayer by lazy {
            ExoPlayer.Builder(itemView.context).apply {
                setSeekBackIncrementMs(5000)
                setSeekForwardIncrementMs(5000)
            }.build()
        }

        fun bind(attachmentItem: AttachmentItem) {
            val file = File(
                attachmentItem.fetchFile()
            )

            video.apply {
                player = exoPlayer
                keepScreenOn = true
            }

            exoPlayer.apply {
                setMediaItem(MediaItem.fromUri(file.toUri(itemView.context)!!))
                prepare()
            }
        }

        companion object {
            fun from(parent: ViewGroup): ChatRoomGalleryVideoViewHolder =
                ChatRoomGalleryVideoViewHolder(
                    LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                        .inflate(R.layout.chat_room_gallery_video_item, parent, false)
                )
        }
    }

companion object {
        const val IMAGE_ITEM = 0
        const val VIDEO_ITEM = 1
    }
```

The xml for the video item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
        android:id="@+id/galleryVideo"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/colorBlack"
        app:controller_layout_id="@layout/preview_custom_video_layout"
        app:hide_on_touch="false"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:player_layout_id="@layout/exo_player_view"
        app:resize_mode="fit"
        app:show_buffering="when_playing"
        app:show_timeout="0"
        app:shutter_background_color="@color/colorBlack"
        app:surface_type="surface_view" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

However, when i scroll to a new item, the previous video does not stop. Same happens when i leave the activity at all. How can i fix that?

Comment: Hay James, have you created git for this code? Or can You Add a complete code so that anyone can use it if they want?

Answer (score 0):

So what i did to solve the problem is this. Every videoViewHolder has an exoPlayer member. In the adapter i keep a Map of <AdapterPosition, exoPlayer instance of each videoView> and also an interface to add each of this pair in the Map. And i use the onViewAttachedToWindow / onViewDetachedFromWindow methods to start the new/ stop the previous video. Here is the code

```
class ChatRoomGalleryAdapter(
    private val appContext: Context
) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    val exoPlayerPositionMap = mutableMapOf<Int, ExoPlayer>()
    interface OnVideoPlayerReady {
        fun addVideoPlayer(position: Int, player: ExoPlayer)
    }

    companion object {
        const val IMAGE_ITEM = 0
        const val VIDEO_ITEM = 1

        //Minimum Video you want to buffer while Playing
        const val MIN_BUFFER_DURATION = 2000

        //Max Video you want to buffer during PlayBack
        const val MAX_BUFFER_DURATION = 5000

        //Min Video you want to buffer before start Playing it
        const val MIN_PLAYBACK_START_BUFFER = 1500

        //Min video You want to buffer when user resumes video
        const val MIN_PLAYBACK_RESUME_BUFFER = 2000
    }

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        when (getItemViewType(position)) {
            IMAGE_ITEM ->
                (holder as ChatRoomGalleryImageViewHolder).bind(files[position])
            VIDEO_ITEM ->
                (holder as ChatRoomGalleryVideoViewHolder).bind(object: OnVideoPlayerReady {
                    override fun addVideoPlayer(position: Int, player: ExoPlayer) {
                        exoPlayerPositionMap[position] = player
                    }
                })
        }
    }

}
```

The ViewHolder class for the Video items

```
class ChatRoomGalleryVideoViewHolder internal constructor(itemView: View) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        private var videoView: PlayerView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.galleryVideo)
        private var exoPlayer: ExoPlayer = exoPlayerBuilder(itemView.context)

        fun bind(videoPlayerReadyCallback: OnVideoPlayerReady) {
            videoView.apply {
                player = exoPlayer
                keepScreenOn = true
                useController = true
                setShowBuffering(SHOW_BUFFERING_WHEN_PLAYING)
            }

            videoPlayerReadyCallback.addVideoPlayer(absoluteAdapterPosition, exoPlayer)
        }

        private fun exoPlayerBuilder(context: Context): ExoPlayer {
            val loadControl: LoadControl = DefaultLoadControl.Builder()
                .setAllocator(DefaultAllocator(true, 16))
                .setBufferDurationsMs(
                    MIN_BUFFER_DURATION,
                    MAX_BUFFER_DURATION,
                    MIN_PLAYBACK_START_BUFFER,
                    MIN_PLAYBACK_RESUME_BUFFER
                )
                .setTargetBufferBytes(-1)
                .setPrioritizeTimeOverSizeThresholds(true).createDefaultLoadControl()

            val player = ExoPlayer.Builder(context).apply {
                setLoadControl(loadControl)
                setSeekBackIncrementMs(5000)
                setSeekForwardIncrementMs(5000)
            }.build()
            return player
        }

        companion object {
            fun from(parent: ViewGroup): ChatRoomGalleryVideoViewHolder =
                ChatRoomGalleryVideoViewHolder(
                    LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                        .inflate(R.layout.chat_room_gallery_video_item, parent, false)
                )
        }
    }
```

And here is the trick. These two methods handle the stop/play of the videos while pageChange

```
//A new view has been attached to to the window. Check if there is an available player for that position of the viewPager. If not return. If yes, then setup the media and play it
override fun onViewAttachedToWindow(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder) {
        super.onViewAttachedToWindow(holder)
        val position = holder.absoluteAdapterPosition
        val attachmentItem = files[position]
        val file = <get the file from the adapter list you provide>
        val uri = file.toUri(appContext) ?: return

        val player = exoPlayerPositionMap[holder.absoluteAdapterPosition] ?: return
        val mediaSource: MediaSource = ProgressiveMediaSource
            .Factory(
                DefaultDataSourceFactory(
                    appContext,
                    Util.getUserAgent(appContext, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID)
                )
            )
            .createMediaSource(MediaItem.fromUri(uri))

        player.apply {
            setMediaSource(mediaSource)
            prepare()
            playWhenReady = true
        }
    }

// A view has been detached from the window. If that was a videoItem (that means it should have a exoplayer in the map for that position, then stop it
    override fun onViewDetachedFromWindow(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder) {
        super.onViewDetachedFromWindow(holder)
        val player = exoPlayerPositionMap[holder.absoluteAdapterPosition] ?: return
        player.stop()
    }
```

P.S. Dont forget on the onPause of the activity to stop all the ExoPlayers

```
override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        viewAdapter.exoPlayerPositionMap.values.forEach {
            it.stop()
        }
    }
```